# Concatenation inside loop does not update dataframes

Tags: python, list, pandas, loops, dataframe

```
for i in [train1,test1]:
    df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(i['Name'], prefix='Name',dummy_na=False)
    #print(df_dummies.head())
    #i.drop('Name',1,inplace=True)
    i = pd.concat([i,df_dummies],axis=1)
    print(i.head())
```

Outputs:

```
       PassengerId  Pclass  Name  Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch   Ticket     Fare  \
0          892       3   Mr.    1  34.5      0      0   330911   7.8292   
1          893       3  Mrs.    0  47.0      1      0   363272   7.0000   
2          894       2   Mr.    1  62.0      0      0   240276   9.6875   
3          895       3   Mr.    1  27.0      0      0   315154   8.6625   
4          896       3  Mrs.    0  22.0      1      1  3101298  12.2875   

   Embarked  Name_Dr.  Name_Master.  Name_Miss.  Name_Mr.  Name_Mrs.  \
0         2         0             0           0         1          0   
1         0         0             0           0         0          1   
2         2         0             0           0         1          0   
3         0         0             0           0         1          0   
4         0         0             0           0         0          1   

   Name_Rev.  Name_other  
0          0           0  
1          0           0  
2          0           0  
3          0           0  
4          0           0
```

But when verify again outside the `for` loop I do not get the dummy variables

```
print(test1.head())
```

Outputs:

```
       PassengerId  Pclass  Name  Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch   Ticket     Fare  \
0          892       3   Mr.    1  34.5      0      0   330911   7.8292   
1          893       3  Mrs.    0  47.0      1      0   363272   7.0000   
2          894       2   Mr.    1  62.0      0      0   240276   9.6875   
3          895       3   Mr.    1  27.0      0      0   315154   8.6625   
4          896       3  Mrs.    0  22.0      1      1  3101298  12.2875   

   Embarked  
0         2  
1         0  
2         2  
3         0  
4         0
```

​Clearly I am missing something here, help me find the error please I think it has something to do with the copy/address of the dataframe

Comment: You assign output to `i`, not to `test1`. Maybe need `test1 = pd.concat([i,df_dummies],axis=1)`

Comment: Okay `i` is `test1` in the 2nd Iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `list comprehension` instead.

```
df_list = [pd.concat([x, pd.get_dummies(x['Name'], prefix='Name',dummy_na=False)], 1)
                                                           for x in [train1, test1]]
```

---

```
df_list[0]

   PassengerId  Pclass  Name  Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch   Ticket     Fare  \
0          892       3   Mr.    1  34.5      0      0   330911   7.8292   
1          893       3  Mrs.    0  47.0      1      0   363272   7.0000   
2          894       2   Mr.    1  62.0      0      0   240276   9.6875   
3          895       3   Mr.    1  27.0      0      0   315154   8.6625   
4          896       3  Mrs.    0  22.0      1      1  3101298  12.2875   

   Embarked  Name_Mr.  Name_Mrs.  
0         2         1          0  
1         0         0          1  
2         2         1          0  
3         0         1          0  
4         0         0          1
```

Comment: @learncode The reason is because you were itearating over a temporary list that had no external reference, and you weren't saving your result in a place from where you could access it later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want assign `df` in `list of DataFrames`. I think your solution does not work, because `concat` return new `DataFrame`.

```
L = [train1,test1]

for i, df in enumerate(L):
    df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['Name'], prefix='Name',dummy_na=False)
    #print(df_dummies.head())
    #i.drop('Name',1,inplace=True)
    L[i] = pd.concat([df,df_dummies],axis=1)


print (L[0])
   PassengerId  Pclass  Name  Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch   Ticket     Fare  \
0          892       3   Mr.    1  34.5      0      0   330911   7.8292   
1          893       3  Mrs.    0  47.0      1      0   363272   7.0000   
2          894       2   Mr.    1  62.0      0      0   240276   9.6875   
3          895       3   Mr.    1  27.0      0      0   315154   8.6625   
4          896       3  Mrs.    0  22.0      1      1  3101298  12.2875   

   Name_Mr.  Name_Mrs.  
0         1          0  
1         0          1  
2         1          0  
3         1          0  
4         0          1
```

Comment: It still does not work if I do `print(test1.head())`. Only works for `print(L(1).head())`, why is this?